# Group checkbox values with .serializeArray()

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, checkbox

I've got groups of checkboxes which contains :

- 1 family

  - Many kind
  - Many kind

    - Many gender
    - Many gender

I've got the following HTML :

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="family" value="familyname1" id="familyname1">
    <fieldset>
        <ul>
            <li id="group1">
                <input type="checkbox" name="kind" value="kindname1" id="kindname1" />
                <ul>
                    <li>
                       <input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="gendername1" value="gendername1" /></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="gendername2" value="gendername2" /></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="group2">
                <input type="checkbox" name="kind" value="kindname2" id="kindname2">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                       <input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="gendername3" value="gendername3"></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="gendername4" value="gendername4"></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
<div id="result"></p> <--- To display the result of my tests
```

On submit I need to give to my dev the checked value with the following JSON string format or something like that :
eg : family=familyname1&familyname2,kind=kindname1,gender=gendername2&gendername3

**In fact I need to group the value by family, kind and gender...**

I try to get something with `.serializeArray()` method but I didn't succeed.

Also, maybe I should rethink or rewrite something in my html tag don't hesitate to tell me. I'm the worst front dev with forms :)

Comment: [`$('form').serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) will list input names and values in the order they're found in the form.

Comment: That's what i saw... :( and I need to give grouped values that's my problem

Comment: Can you use hidden input fields for groups?

Comment: certainly but I'm so bad with the forms that I do not know how to use them correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build an array that store your sorting order, then get the form elements in an object array using `serializeArray`, and get the final string using jQuery `map` and js `join`.

Code:

```
var sortOrders = {
    "family": 1,
        "kind": 2,
        "gender": 3
};

$('#demo').click(function () {

    var arr = $('form').serializeArray()

    $('#result').text(arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return sortOrders[a.name] > sortOrders[b.name] ? 1 : -1;
    }).map(function (elem) {
        return elem.name + '=' + elem.value;
    }).join("&"));

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/W9Qu5/

Comment: ASAP I'll expand my answer with more info